# Numpy random normal over columns

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to generate a `NumPy` `ndarray` which has `c` columns and `n` rows but filled with numbers taken from a `random` `normal` distribution. I'd like the distribution to be normal over the columns i.e. I want the column `c/2` to have values close to the mean (making the random number in column `c/2` to be higher than the ones to the left or right of it).

Is there an inbuilt `NumPy` function for this?

If there isn't, can we specify in `NumPy` random normal to give us values within a band from the distribution so that i can fill the columns individually?

Comment: Define "close to the mean". Do you want the middle column (is that what you mean by c/2?) to have values from a narrower distribution (reduce sigma) or the closest from a sample (sort the rows?)

Comment: If I have 3 columns then I'd want column 0 to have say 0.25, column 1 to have 0.5 and column 2 to have 0.24. therefore the magnitude of values would follow the bell curve with the mean at the middle column.

Comment: So in your example `[0.25, 0.5, 0.24]`, the number 0.5 is the mean? Of what? "To follow the bell curve" does not mean to have smaller values, then larger, then smaller again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you could do something like this:

```
scales = [0.01, 0.1, 1, 0.1, 0.01]
arrays = [np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=s, size=(3)) for s in scales]
np.vstack(arrays).T

array([[ 0.0021688 , -0.11704194,  0.84077943,  0.13570005, -0.01371024],
       [ 0.01726078, -0.00167188, -0.85074286,  0.01729595,  0.00696604],
       [ 0.00169041, -0.11899872,  0.34075113,  0.08299408,  0.00296036]])
```